# how to cache image generated by php

Tags: php, image, caching

i made a file to print out the image file with W and H i define by get method

but my problem is to cache this pictures

i add this headers to the file

```
@header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
@header("Pragma: private");
@header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,filemtime($full_path)));

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])
       &&
  (strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == filemtime($full_path))) {
  // send the last mod time of the file back
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($full_path)).' GMT',true, 304);
  exit;
}else
{
     @header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($full_path)) . ' GMT');
     @header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
     @imagejpeg($image);
}
```

but my problem is some pictures are cached ok , but others are not , and sometime pictures inside album not appear until if i disable the cache header

is my headers are correct ? , and about the cache do i have to use - or + to set the time cache how its work ?

Comment: It's not good practise to hide all your errors like that. Have a look at setting PHP's [error_log ini directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) so you can track errors instead of silencing them.

Comment: I use PHP everyday, and didn't even recognise what the @ was at first!

Comment: `@` was first to hide function errors if exists like execute function in silent mod without printing any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because they use Htaccess with mod_expires?

**Example #1:**

```
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# expire GIF images after a month in the client's cache
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
# HTML documents are good for a week from the
# time they were changed
ExpiresByType text/html M604800
```

[Read This Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

**Example #2:**

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
```

Comment: is this gonna cache all the pictures at the gallery the thumb and the big one ? , thank u ill use this code this was very useful

Comment: Its a example with Htaccess(Apache 2+ and Mod_Expires)... read the documentation :)